# How to show the same layout in android wear and mobile at same time

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

I have a layout of some textviews.The textviews are changing depend on a timer.

I need to show this layout in mobile and android wear at same time.Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the easy way:

1. create a version of the layout for both mobile and Wear
2. operate on the data (Model), not the layouts (Views). Sync the data using the normal Wear data layer routine and just put it into the layout

The data layer tends to work really fast, so the effect should be just as you desired.

Comment: :So i need to create different layout for both mobile and android wear

Comment: Yes, and then populate it with data. Your application should two modules, one for mobile and one for wear (Android Studio IDE will create those for you)

Comment: I have created like that two modules.But when i show the layout in mobile what should i do for android wear ? how i show that layout in android wear ?

Comment: There are many ways, depending on whether you want it to show automatically or after user turns the app on. In the first case, create a Wear notification for your app (http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html). In the second, simply install the app and synchronize data only when it is turned on.

Comment: Thank You and creating the notification in android wear,right ? How can i get back to you when any doubt came ? because this is the first time i works on android wear  ?

Comment: Leave another comment here or mail me at kelevandos [at] gmail [dot] com. Also, please mark this answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks! :-)

Comment: yes kelevandos.I will mark once it works I doing on it.Now i sending an email.Please reply to it :)